# Excel formula is not being applied to some entries

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, excel-formula

I have a workbook that gets its data from a SharePoint library. The idea is to automatically generate reports from the excel workbook and send automatic emails with the report attached. Problem is: recently, after the workbook refreases, formulas are missing in some cells making the reports incorrect. What is causing the formulas not to be applied in some cells?

[image: Excel sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure filters are cleared before inserting the formula. Filters make some rows hidden and the formula is not applied to them.

Comment: Already checked that. In fact I just noticed that the more records are added the more previous records get deleted...